# django field comparing values to record

Tags: python, django, database

I have a field that records the time, but I need to rewrite this value. My app seems to chronometre and I need to keep the best time. How can I do that ? For example, I have 5 laps and the results:

- 1:0:0
- 2:0:0
- 1:5:0
- 3:0:0
- 0:5:0

Database should record the latest 0:5:0. I have only 1 field to do that.

Comment: so what's a problem? - calculate min value using js, serialize it and send to your view

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the time strings into seconds and store that value in the DB.

Alternatively, you can either use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with a custom `key` function:

```
times = ["1:0:0",
         "2:0:0",
         "1:5:0",
         "3:0:0",
         "0:5:0"]

print min(times, key=lambda x: [int(i.lstrip('0')) for i in x.split(':')])
```